# mysql getting precount table field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take data from mysql where one of the fields is calculated in mysql.

Example : I have an X, Y and Z fields. I want to create a new field called 'A', where 'A' is the calculation value of (X + Y) / Z.
The catch is that Z != 0, so if Z is 0 then Z will be changed to 1 to avoid infinite numbers (1/0 = ??).

The question is can I calculate this into a new field in mysql??

What I came up is this

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, ((X+Y)/Z) as A FROM table
```

However, I still can't filter Z so that if Z==0, then Z=1. Can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User MySQL CASE WHEN Syntax:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Z != 0 THEN ((X+Y)/Z) 
ELSE X)  AS A 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of `case`

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, ((X+Y)/ CASE WHEN Z != 0 THEN Z ELSE 1 END) as A FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Decode statement here will help

```
select x,y, DECODE (z,0,1,z) denom,((X+Y)/denom) from table 
Syntax DECODE (what,(when,then),default)
```

Let me know if this gives the correct result